# Video not showing up on WordPress page

Tags: wordpress

For some reason this video isn't showing up on a WordPress site, the src is correct. Is their an error in the code? It's being used as a text widget.

```
    <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B" WIDTH="400" HEIGHT="240" CODEBASE="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
    <PARAM name="SRC" VALUE="http://www.preschooladvantage.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/PA-Presentation-small.m4v">
    <PARAM name="AUTOPLAY" VALUE="false">
    <PARAM name="CONTROLLER" VALUE="true">
    <EMBED SRC="http://www.preschooladvantage.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/PA-Presentation-small.m4v" WIDTH="400" HEIGHT="240" AUTOPLAY="false" CONTROLLER="true" PLUGINSPAGE="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"></EMBED>
    </OBJECT>
```

Comment: Have you checked the HTML output? Does it look like expected? If not try to use an HTML/PHP widget or just use a [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/) that does have that feature.

Comment: ok i'll give that a shot